# SQL query to extract ranges from table of integers

Tags: sql, select, sequence, gaps-and-islands, ansi-sql

This may have been answered here before, but I have no clue how to search for it, so my apologies if it's a duplicate. I have a table with integer column, which holds number in sequence.

Some of numbers is missing due to removing of rows:

```
+-------+
| _auto |
+-------+
|   0   |
|   1   |
|   2   |
|  5    |
|  6    |
|  7    |
|   9   |
|  11   |
|  12   |
|  13   |
|  14   |
|   16  |
|   17  |
|  19   |
|  20   |
+-------+
```

What I want, is to write SQL query which gave me a table consists of ranges on this column.

```
+----+----+
|  F |  T |
+----+----+
|  0 |  2 |
|  5 |  7 |
|  9 |  9 |
| 11 | 14 |
| 16 | 17 |
| 19 | 20 |
+----+----+
```

I'll be using it with QT4::QSqlDatabase driver, so it would be nice if it's work on any compatible database (ANSI SQL), not only PostgreSQL.

I believe in this algorithm: (1) select rows, such that there is no rows with values *_auto+1*; (2) the same, but *_auto-1*; (3) union this two selects.

But I have no understanding how to write first two selects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequences of numbers have a property:  if you subtract an sequence from them, then the result is a constant.  The following query uses this observation:

```
select min(_auto) as f, max(_auto) as t
from (select n._auto, row_number() over (order by n._auto) as seqnum
      from numbers n
     ) n
group by (_auto - seqnum);
```

Comment: Ok I spent a while trying to understand how this works, and here's a layman's explanation: say you have a sequence of numbers `1, 2, 3, 150, 151, 152`. `row_number()` will output the index of each row as sorted by the number (`order by n._auto`). This gives `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` (seqnum). Then the `group by` clause at the end groups on the original number minus the seqnum, in this case `0, 0, 0, 146, 146, 146`. Then it outputs the minimum and maximum of those rows. Makes a lot of sense once you think about it but took a while to grok.